# Фильтрация таблицы с помощью select vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как отфильтровать таблицу по значению select. Например, если выбирается select с value admin то показать строки таблицы со значением admin.

P.S: Брать напрямую значение v-model и сравнить через цикл и отключать не прошедшие проверку элементы через display none или можно по другому?

```js
<template>
  <select name="select" v-model="selected">
  <option disabled value="">Выберите один из вариантов</option>
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value"> {{ option.text }} </option>
 </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data: function() {
  return {
   selected: '',
   options: [
    { text: 'User', value: 'user'},
    { text: 'Admin', value: 'admin'},
    { text: 'superAdmin', value: 'superAdmin'}
   ]
  }
 }
}
</script>

// Table

<template>
 <div class="container">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th v-for='column in columns' v-on:click='sortTable(column)'>
     {{ column }}
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr v-for='row in filteredUsers'>
    <td v-for="column in columns">{{row[column]}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 
</template>

<script>

export default {
 props: ['searchQuery'],
  data: function() {
    return {
   selected: 'admin',
   rows: [
    { name: 'John', email: "john@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' },
    { name: 'Jane', email: "jane@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' },
    { name: 'Paul', email: "paul@gmail.com", root: 'Admin' },
    { name: 'Kate', email: "kate@gmail.com", root: 'Admin' },
    { name: 'Amanda', email: "amanda@gmail.com", root: 'User' },
    { name: 'Steve', email: "steve@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' },
    { name: 'Keith', email: "keith@gmail.com", root: 'User' },
    { name: 'Don', email: "don@gmail.com", root: 'Admin' },
    { name: 'Susan', email: "susan@gmail.com", root: 'superAdmin' }
   ]
    }
 },
 computed: {
  filteredUsers: function() {
   return this.rows.filter(function(user) {
    return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1;
   }.bind(this));
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Добавьте условие в функцию `filteredUsers`. У вас проблема с этим, или с тем, как получить value селекта?

Comment: ну с селекта мы получаем value через v-model (с передачей однофайловых компонентов знаком т.к область видимости изолирована, придется  отслеживать инпут и через пропс передавать) ну с этим ладно. А что за условие? не могли бы вы пример написать

Comment: `return this.rows.filter(function(user) {
    return (user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) && (user.root == value_селекта);
   }.bind(this));`

Comment: А как отобразить список таблицы до выбора value select, просто с помощью 'или' список элементов таблицы не выводится пока value selecta не будет известно.

Comment: Добавьте в условие проверку, что value определено -
 как то так например: `(user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCas‌​e()) > -1) &&  (!value_селекта || (user.root == value_селекта))`